# Filter not changing on backspace press - radgridview - C#

Tags: c#, textbox, radgridview, backspace, textchanged

In my program I have a text box and on text change a filter is applied to my RadGrid. However, on backspace the filter is not reapplied.

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CompositeFilterDescriptor searchFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
            searchFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor("product", FilterOperator.Contains, txt_search.Text));
            this.radGridView1.EnableFiltering = true;
            this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].EnableFiltering = true;
            this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].ShowFilteringRow = false;
            this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.ShowFilteringRow = false;
            this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].ShowTotals = true;
            this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].ShowFilterCellOperatorText = false;

            if (txt_search.Text != "")
            {
                this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].FilterDescriptors.Add(searchFilter);
            }

            foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Rows)
            {
                if (row.ChildRows.Count == 0)
                {
                    row.IsVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.IsVisible = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong searching the grid. Please try again and contact I.T. if this problem persists.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another function which needs to be generated that is applied on backspace?

This code is taken from another program I have which is written in VB.net and converted. The filter works as it should in the VB version and is reapplied when text is removed etc.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Webforms, desktop? Is the actual question "why isn't TextChanged raised when I press Backspace" ? Have you tried *debugging*?

Comment: Hi, Text changed is raised when I press backspace. However, the filter isn't removed.

Comment: On debugging it also changes my search filter to what it should. The rows just don't reappear

Comment: BTW there are quite a few places where the code can be improved, whether C# or VB.NET, eg just store `this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0]` in a variable instead of searching for it all the time. Your code keeps adding `FilterDescriptor` instances to the grid and template for every change - how many are there by the time you hit Backspace?

Comment: The filter isn't remove because you don't remove it. You add *another* one. If the new one is less restrictive, the previous, more restrictive ones take precedence

Comment: Ahh okay! That makes sense, so I need to remove the filter each time the function is called? Or is that bad practice and a slow way of doing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163790/discussion-between-benjiiiii-and-panagiotis-kanavos).